# No View Found Error While Adding a DialogFragment Inside RecyclerView.ViewHolder

Tags: android

For reference, I'm using the Android SDK in Java. I'm encountering an error when trying to add a DialogFragment inside a RecyclerView.ViewHolder item. This is my current app structure:

MainActivity:

1. Home Fragment
2. Lockdown Fragment
3. Settings Fragment

Within the Lockdown Fragment, I have a RecyclerView. One of the ViewHolders / RecyclerView items is called LockdownListViewHolder. Note that the structure is now MainActivity -> LockdownFragment (w/ RecyclerView object) -> LockdownListViewHolder (RecyclerView item).

I want to create and display a full screen DialogFragment when a button is pressed in LockdownListViewHolder.

This is my code for the LockdownListViewHolder:

```
public class LockdownListViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

    /*
     * PRIVATE FIELDS
     */
    private final RecyclerView mLockdownListRecyclerView;
    private final RecyclerView.Adapter mLockdownListAdapter;
    private final MaterialButton mLockdownCreationButton;
    private final LockdownManager mLockdownManager;
    private final FragmentManager mFragmentManager;
    private final Context mApplicationContext;

    /*
     * CONSTRUCTOR: responsible for injecting and instantiating fields.
     */
    public LockdownListViewHolder(View itemView, LockdownManager lockdownManager, FragmentManager fragmentManager, Context applicationContext) {
        super(itemView);

        mLockdownManager = lockdownManager;
        mFragmentManager = fragmentManager;
        mApplicationContext = applicationContext;
        mLockdownListAdapter = new LockdownListAdapter(mLockdownManager, mApplicationContext);

        mLockdownListRecyclerView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view_lockdown_fragment_lockdown_list);
        mLockdownListRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(mApplicationContext));
        mLockdownListRecyclerView.setAdapter(mLockdownListAdapter);

        mLockdownCreationButton = itemView.findViewById(R.id.button_lockdown_creation);
        mLockdownCreationButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    /*
     * bindModel: method responsible for retrieving the necessary data and supplying it
     * to the appropriate Views.
     */
    public void bindModel() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        LockdownCreationDialogFragment lockdownCreationDialogFragment = new LockdownCreationDialogFragment();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = mFragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN);
        fragmentTransaction.add(android.R.id.content, lockdownCreationDialogFragment)
                .addToBackStack(null).commit();
    }
```

With this code, I'm getting the following exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x1020002 (android:id/content) for fragment LockdownCreationDialogFragment{e821d4f} (22414275-c8ee-4362-8cd5-f16b149d2838 id=0x1020002)
at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.createView(FragmentStateManager.java:513)
at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.moveToExpectedState(FragmentStateManager.java:282)
at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2189)
at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:2100)
at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:2002)
at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager$5.run(FragmentManager.java:524)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:226)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:313)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8663)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:567)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1135)
```

I've made sure that the FragmentManager that I'm passing to LockdownListViewHolder is from getChildFragmentManager(). I have the container ID set as `android.R.id.content` in the FragmentTransaction call, as it is in the documentation here: https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/components/dialogs#FullscreenDialog.

I'm not quite sure where I'm going wrong with this. Admittedly, the concepts of Activities, Fragments, Containers, Views, Windows, etc. are all starting to blend together and I have a feeling that I'm doing something that's just structured wrong / trying to access something I can't.

Any advice would be appreciated.